# Alias Command for Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

While at work, I want to use the CLI to be more productive on my Windows machine. What command, in Windows, would be a replacement for the `alias` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
doskey com=a long command $*
```

Here `$*` expands to everything typed after `com`. For example, `com Hi!` would be expanded to `a long command Hi!`

- This not limited to the `cmd.exe` shell – it works with any program that uses a Win32 console window. (For example, for Python's interactive shell, use `doskey /exefile:python.exe ...`)

See [`doskey /?`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753867(WS.10).aspx) for usage. The aliases can also be added programatically; see [Console Aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682057(v=VS.85).aspx) for the API.

---

To apply aliases automatically whenever `cmd.exe` is launched:

1. Put them in a text file, in the form `alias=expansion`:

   ```
   com=very long example command
   cd=cd /d $*
   ```

   I keep my aliases in `%AppData%\doskey.txt`.
2. Create a batch script containing the `doskey` command:

   ```
   @echo off

   doskey /macrofile:"%AppData%\doskey.txt"
   ```

   Of course, point `/macrofile` to the location you have chosen in step 1.

   A good name for this script is `%AppData%\autorun.cmd`.
3. In Registry, open key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and point the value `AutoRun` to the script.

   1. Run `regedit`, navigate to the given key.
   2. If a value named `AutoRun` does not exist, create it: *right-click → New → String*
   3. Modify the associated data to point to wherever your autorun script from #2 is located.

Comment: I attempted this method on windows 7, but had no luck.  when I attempt to directly execute the `autorun.cmd`, I get an `Invalid macro definition` error (I turned `@echo on` to see the output).  are there any suggestions for what might cause this?

Comment: nevermind.  Just to let you know, there is an error in your answer.  the autorun.cmd file needs to say `doskey /macrofile=...`.  note the `=` instead of the `:`

Comment: You can simply save the current configuration: `doskey /macros:all > "%AppData%\doskey.txt"`. This file has sections per EXE name, such as `[cmd.exe]`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the "alias" command. Dos/NT command prompts support "alias" as a command with the following syntax:

alias

See the wikipedia article for details:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)

Comment: Doesn't look like it, I just tried it. Win XP.  But that wikipedia article does mention powershell and 4DOS and 4NT having a command for aliases but maybe not that syntax.

Comment: What about using Set?

I just tested in XP, set ckh = "George" and it set an environment variable ckd as "George". Is this an analog to alias?

Comment: @music2myyear  No. An alias is like a substitution. So typing C:\>doskey tt=blah <ENTER> that sets up an alias tt=blah,  means when you type tt and press ENTER, then it acts like you typed blah and pressed enter. So it's like a shortcut. With set, if you do set ckh=George  Then ckh ENTER will still be ckh ENTER.  But %ckh% will use the contents of the ckh environemnt variable i.e. George. The %s are not so convenient as with an alias,

Comment: @music2myyear but it's a very different concept really. A variable is like a container with a name and a value  and is meant to change at times you want. An alias is like a shorthand way of saying something, it's more static.. if you kept changing your aliases you'd get confused.. 'cos they're meant to be easily memorable shorthands for specific commands with certain options you don't want to have to retype.

Comment: Got it and thank you for the explanation. I've never much gotten into programming or scripting or admin-ing on *nix systems and so was (obviously) not familiar with the concept. But now I'm a little more so thanks to y'all.