# What is the cmd equivalent of Bash's "type"

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

How can I find out where a program is running from, or if it is an alias (and if it is an alias, then what it is an alias to)?

Comment: Do you mean under Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd.exe` does not have an equivalent command to `bash`'s `type`.  The `type` command in `cmd.exe` operates like Unix's `cat`, and borrows the name from the old CP/M command of the same name.

Unless a third-party program is installed, the only way to do aliases in `cmd.exe` is through the old `doskey /macros` command - use `doskey /macros:all` to list all active ones - which is likely always going to return empty since no one uses them nor has since about 1993 or so.

The following are `cmd.exe`'s "builtins", or commands internal to it:

`{drive-letter}:` `:{line-label}` `call` `cd` `chcp` `chdir` `color` `copy` `ctty` `date` `del` `delete` `dir` `echo`  `endlocal` `era` `erase` `exit` `for` `goto` `help` `if` `lh` `loadhigh` `path` `popd` `prompt` `pushd` `prompt` `rem` `ren` `rename` `rmdir` `rd` `set` `setlocal` `shift` `time` `title` `type` `ver` `verify`

Answer (score -1):

Since cmd.exe itself doesn't support aliases, you can probably get away with using [`which`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/which.htm) instead. If you are using any addons which provide aliases, consult their documentation.

Comment: [The Win32 console subsystem provides an alias mechanism for any Win32 console programs that want it.  `cmd` is one Win32 program that uses it.](http://superuser.com/questions/269553/)