# Unable to CD into volumes

Tags: windows, diskpart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using cd Command in Windows Command Line, Can't Navigate to D:\](https://superuser.com/questions/135214/using-cd-command-in-windows-command-line-cant-navigate-to-d)

After using diskpart to create T:\ I can't actually cd into T:\

When I try

```
cd T:\
```

It does NOTHING at all.

How can I fix this

Code for creating T:\

```
select disk 0

convert dynamic

create volume simple size=20480
rem create simple volume simple size=51200
assign letter=T
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're using the right syntax. As a leftover from MS-DOS times, changing *drive* and *directory* are two separate operations in the command-line shell.

For example, to go to **`T:\`**, you first change the drive to **`T:`**, then the directory to **`\`**:

```
T:
cd \
```

In Windows NT, the `cmd.exe` shell allows combining both operations again using the `/d` option:

```
cd /d T:\
```

---

A bit more detail. When you run `cd T:\` as in your own example, it *does* change the directory, just not the drive. In MS-DOS and DOS-based versions of Windows, each drive letter had its own separate "current directory", [as explained in this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563).

Windows NT only has one "current directory" per process; however, the command shell and its `cd` command have to emulate the old behavior for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Does windows support any form of alias so I can make cd always use `cd /d` ?

Comment: In batch files, no. In interactive shells, yes - [using `doskey`](http://superuser.com/a/269567/1686). Also, you might find the `pushd`/`popd` command pair convenient; they don't require the separate steps.